# Conditional statements-Nested statements

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements, scanf, conditional-operator

```
Men                    Women        Category
<0.90                   <0.80        Normalweight
0.90 to 0.99     0.80 to 0.84    Overweight
1.0+                    0.85+            Obesity
```

Given length of waist(inches) and hip(inches) calculate its WHR and print its respective category as "Normalweight" or "Overweight" or "Obesity".
This is the code for above question

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
  int a,b;
  char e;
  float d;
  scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
  scanf("%c",&e);
  d=a/b;
  if(d<0.90 && e=='m'){
    printf("Normalweight");}
  else if(d>=0.90 && d<=0.99 ){
    if(e=='m'){
    printf("Overweight");}
  }
  else if(d>0.80 && d<0.84){
    if(e=='f'){
    printf("Overweight");}
  }else{
   printf("Obesity");}
  
  
}
```

if i give any inputs
the answer i am getting is
Obesity

Comment: `d=a/b;` you perform integer division, then convert to float afterwards. You need to convert to floats first before dividing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

For starters use meaningful names for variables.

Secondly change the format string in this call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%c",&e);
```

the following way

```
scanf( " %c", &e );
       ^^^
```

Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip white space characters including the new line character `'\n'` that is placed in the input buffer due to pressing key Enter.

Thirdly in the assignment expression in this statement

```
d=a/b;
```

there is used the integer arithmetic. Change the statement for example like

```
d = ( float )a / b;
```

Your if-else statement is unclear and as a result wrong. For example there is absent an ouput of the string "Normalweight" for women.

To make the program more clear and readable you can introduce a switch statement like for example

```
switch ( e )
{
case 'm':
    if ( d < 0.9f ) puts( "Normalweight" );
    else if ( d < 1.0f ) puts( "Overweight" );
    else puts( "Obesity" );
    break;

case 'f':
    if ( d < 0.8f ) puts( "Normalweight" );
    else if ( d < 0.85f ) puts( "Overweight" );
    else puts( "Obesity" );
    break;
};
```

Though there is present duplicated calls of puts nevertheless the code more clear and readable.

In general you should check success or failure of calls of `scanf` and whether acceptable values as for example `'f'` or `'m'` were entered.